# Upload to Cloudflare Stream without running out of memory

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to upload videos to cloudflare stream. The problem is that I'm running out of memory.

What I'm currently doing is:
1 - I receive the file through the request using multer
2 - I send the file using tus-js (streaming the file with 8 MB chunk size).

The problem is that, If I upload a 200mb video, it will eat 200mb of the memory. I think I need to use busboy, but I don't find any tutorial on that.

What can I do ?

Comment: Can you include an example of your existing code?

Comment: u need cleanup after 10 chinks and u will not recieve this message (i think)

Comment: multer depends on busboy, without minimal reproducible code we can't help

Comment: Multer provides me the file buffer on the request, then I use that to upload to cloudflare stream using tus-js. My multer does not have any configuration and the tus-js upload is the sample code from cloudflare stream upload.